# Error with showCloseButton when creating toast

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm working through the "Ionic 4 Firebase with Angular-Build PWA, Native Android, iOS" tutorial on Skillshare. One of the requirements is to create a toast that shows up when the user signs up on the app, with a close button.

I've followed the examples to the tee, but "showCloseButton: true" has a red error line bellow the whole statement.

This is my code:

```
async presentToast(message) {
    const toast = await this.toastController.create({
      message,
      duration: 1500,
      showCloseButton: true,
      position: this.platform.is('desktop') ? 'top' : 'bottom'
    });
    toast.present();
  }
```

And this is the error message I'm getting:

> (property) showCloseButton: boolean 
>   Argument of type '{ message: any; duration: number; showCloseButton: boolean; position: "top" | "bottom"; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ToastOptions'.
>
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'showCloseButton' does not exist in type 'ToastOptions'.ts(2345)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of toastr are you using? And why is this question tagged both angular and angularJS? Anyway according to the documentation the property should be named `closeButton`, not showCloseButton.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it should be version 4. It's all code that was copied from the Ionic documentation, with the showCloseButton and position lines added to it.

Regards to the tags, I wasn't show which specific tags to use.

I tried using closeButton and it still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ionic4 does not have a close button property for the Toast. But you can add a button with the `'cancel'` role as explained in [the documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/toast#creating).

```
const toast = await this.toastController.create({
  header: 'Toast header',
  message: 'Click to Close',
  position: 'top',
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Done',
      role: 'cancel',
      handler: () => {
        console.log('Cancel clicked');
      }
    }
  ]
});
toast.present();
```